# Bootstrap responsive text-align not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make some text center only on small viewport size and below.  Wider than small should be left-align.  For some reason, when I contiue to shrink the viewport, the text left-aligns.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nqxhs5j/5/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="box" class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-sm-12 text-md-left text-sm-center">
        Center me on col-sm, otherwise, left align me
    </div>
</div>

#box{
  width:600px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: @Amalnandan Bootstrap v5

Comment: u already got the answer right : )

Comment: Calling for question to be re-opened.  This is not a duplicate.  This is a question specifically about responsive bootstrap class behavior, not CSS text alignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Bootstrap 5, you need to use `text-sm-start`:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div id="box" class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 offset-md-3 text-center text-sm-start">
      Center me on col-sm, otherwise, left align me
    </div>
  </div>
```